# How to Save text in TextViewEx to clipboard

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, clipboardmanager

> This my code and some error when i want get text in recyclerview and save in clipboard.
>   my error with :

```
   holder.btnCopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", containerTextView.getText());
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

and this is adaptercode :

```
public class LinearCardListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LinearCardListAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
private Context context;
private List<TravelCard> travelCards;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView containerImageView;
        public TextView containerTextView;
    public LinearLayout textLayout;
    public int myHeight;
    public Button deleteItem;
    public TextViewEx subtitleView;
    public Button btnCopy;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_layout);
        containerImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_container);
        btnCopy = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_copy);
        containerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
        subtitleView = (TextViewEx) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle_view);
        deleteItem = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        myHeight = containerImageView.getHeight();
    }
}
public LinearCardListAdapter(Context context ,List<TravelCard> travelCards , RecyclerView recyclerView){
    this.context = context;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    this.travelCards = travelCards;
}
@Override
public LinearCardListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View myView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.linear_list_card_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder=  new MyViewHolder(myView);
    return myViewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final int newPos = position;
    final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = holder;
    Glide.with(context).load(context.getResources().getIdentifier(context.getPackageName() + ":drawable/" + travelCards.get(position).getImagePath(),null,null)).into(holder.containerImageView);
```

holder.subtitleView.setText(travelCards.get(position).getSubtitle(), true);

```
    holder.containerTextView.setText(travelCards.get(position).getTitle());
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
            recyclerView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);


            if (myViewHolder.containerImageView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
                DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

                float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;


                float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
                int screen_height_pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpHeight, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                int half_screen_height = screen_height_pixels / 2;


                int container_height_pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


                int center = half_screen_height - (container_height_pixels / 2);


                int[] loc_screen = {0, 0};
                myViewHolder.containerImageView.getLocationOnScreen(loc_screen);

                int final_loc = ((loc_screen[1] - center) * 100) / half_screen_height;


                myViewHolder.containerImageView.setTranslationY(-final_loc * 0.6f * density - 160);

            }
        }
    });
    holder.btnCopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", containerTextView.getText());
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "متن در حافظه موقت دستگاه ذخیره شد",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    holder.deleteItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            travelCards.remove(newPos);
            notifyItemRemoved(newPos);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(newPos, travelCards.size());
        }
    });
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return travelCards.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`containerTextView` is one of your holder class attributes. so you have to use `holder.containerTextView` to access it instead of `containerTextView` alone.

so you must modify this line (in `holder.btnCopy.setOnClickListener(...)` method:

```
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", containerTextView.getText());
```

and change it to:

```
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", holder.containerTextView.getText());
```